# processing multiple responses from user in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am creating a chatbot in Dialogflow for healthcare department where user will enter his symptoms(I have some symptom stored under  entity called symptom) and i want to identify disease user is suffering from by processing his responses.
Any help for this? 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have few questions to identify the symptoms and then after you identify the symptoms, there should be a mapping of symptoms with the disease (probably in a cloud function or any other backend u prefer). By having a map of symptoms and diseases you should be able to do your task.